# Reducing exact SVP to exact SIVP

Tags: lattice-crypto, reduction

In "Efficient reductions among lattice problems" by Micciancio (2007) it is said, that

**SVP reduces to SIVP in their exact versions**.

I did not found anything about this fact, is a reduction that trivial?
Does the same hold for their approximation versions?

Answer (score 5):

It is non-trivial, You need to see the Corollary 7 in [Mic07](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edaniele/papers/SIVP-CVP.html), Micciancio proved that a  series of problems (including CVP and SIVP) in the Euclidean norm are equivalent in their exact version under polynomial time rank-preserving reductions. And in [GMSS99](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(99)00083-6), Goldreich et al showed a reduction from SVP to CVP, So, combination of both, you got a reduction from SVP to SIVP. As for the approximation versions, you could see Noah Stephens-Davidowitz's paper [NSD16](http://www.noahsd.com/latticeproblems.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!

Comment: In Stephens-Davidowitz's paper, it is mentioned that SIVP_gamma reduces to SVP_gamma, but he said that he is not aware of any other source. He gave a proof, as far as I can see, but his paper is not been officially published. Is there anything behind? Does the relation hold?

Comment: Yes, But I don't know if it will be published later, Maybe this proof is too trivial to published, In fact,  the reduction is from $SIVP_{\sqrt{n}\gamma}$ to $SVP_{\gamma}$. Maybe, If someone can do better than $\sqrt{n}$ between two approximate factors, there will be a publication

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks again!